# If ReadKey code running twice

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a simple health and ammo 'game'. It is supposed to display current health and ammo values but on key press some code runs twice then sometimes not at all but I can't see any exceptions.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FGameF
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 100, y = 100;
            Console.WriteLine("FGameF -- Hacking Test Game -- For DLL Injection");
            Console.WriteLine("Aim: Change Health And Ammo Values");
            Console.Write("Health: " + x + " Ammo: " + y);
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.D1)
                    {
                        Console.Write("\rHealth: " + x + " Ammo: " + y);                       
                        x--;
                    }
                    else if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.D2)
                    {                 
                        Console.Write("\rHealth: " + x + " Ammo: " + y);        
                        y--;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Sorry, I am not the best at this. Sometimes, 2 gets taken off x when the key is only pressed one, same for y. But sometimes, nothing happens at all on press of y after a few times of x vise-versa.

Comment: *but on key press some code runs twice then sometimes not at all* - Which code runs twice and sometimes not at all? I can't figure out your description at all. Please try harder.

Comment: Please only use the `visual-studio` tag if your question is *about* Visual Studio.  See the tag description: "Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality, not just a question regarding your code."

Comment: `x--;
                        if (x.ToString().Length == 2)
                        {
                            Console.Write("\rHealth: " + x + "  Ammo: " + y + " ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write("\rHealth: " + x + " Ammo: " + y + " ");                       
                        }     `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner code should read the keyboard once, and then check the value in the two if-statements, like this:

```
var c = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
if (c == ConsoleKey.D1)
{
    Console.Write("\rHealth: " + x + " Ammo: " + y);                       
    x--;
}
else if (c == ConsoleKey.D2)
{                 
    Console.Write("\rHealth: " + x + " Ammo: " + y);        
    y--;
}
```

Also it seems peculiar that you first print the values, and then the decrease takes place, so you might want to turn that around.

Comment: Thanks, this works but one thing. An extra 0 is added on the end and I can't work why. `FGameF -- Hacking Test Game -- For DLL Injection
Aim: Change Health And Ammo Values
Health: 99 Ammo: 9700` This is printed code from console

Comment: Could it be that those are a result of the keys that you are typing?